# Unindentified Offset Warning comparing arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I'm getting some unindentified offset warnings in php.

```
<?php

/*****************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************/
/**** Queries Active Directory For Overview Off All Employees ****/
/*****************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************/

/*-------------*/
/* Credentials */
/*-------------*/

    $ldapserver = 'srv-dc-01.vex.local';
    $ldapuser = 'SamL@vex'; 
    $ldappass = 'xxxx!';
    $ldaptree = "OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=vex,DC=local";

    $secret = '}84lSB+-cdH{?[';

/*------------------------*/
/* Connect & Authenticate */
/*------------------------*/

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); // For LDAP v3

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

/*------------------------*/
/* Query Active Directory */
/*------------------------*/

    $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(cn=*)", array("cn","title","mail","telephonenumber","thumbnailphoto")) or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

    $count = $data['count'];

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>sive</title>
        <style> 
            .box {
                float:left;
                width:400px;
                height:100px;
                border-style:dashed;
                border-width:2px;
                border-color:grey;
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .picture {
                float:left;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {


        $blacklist = array("BES Admin","Network Administrator","SBSMonAcct","Directory Updater","NL Admin","Standard User","Standard User with administration links","SSL Admin");
        foreach ($blacklist as $key => $value){
            if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === $value) { continue; } 
        }

        /*if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BES Admin") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Network Administrator") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SBSMonAcct") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Directory Updater") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "NL Admin") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Standard User") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Standard User with administration links") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SSL Admin") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Vente-Exclusive.com Club") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Vente-Exclusive.com Logistics") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServer2005MSSQLUser\$WIN-EUGSO7LO7PY\$BLACKBERRY") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Sharepoint TFS") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Jobs Autoreply") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Printer Lookup2") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Printer Lookup") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "VPN Lookup") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "WallaceBackups") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Info - Yaminta") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Service - Yaminta") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "QA -. Test Mailbox") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Vente-Exclusive.com Android App") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Vente-Exclusive.com Social") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "FashionDays") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "KTN - Vente-Exclusive Admin") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Skype") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "WSSSERVICE") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Accounting Robot") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "NL - Amsterdam - Main meeting room") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Ticketing Authenticator") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser\$SRV-DC-01") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser\$SRV-DC-01") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser\$VEX-SRV-NL-01") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser\$VEX-SRV-NL-01") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser\$SRV-DC-02") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser\$SRV-DC-02") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_London") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_NewYork") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_Paris") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_Milan") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_Antwerp") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_HongKong") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM65_02_Barcelona") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM111_01_Coton") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM111_01_Silk") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "BE_HUM111_01_Leather") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "0024d63772ec") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "0c607621979d") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "000085ffbde8") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "0088653e354e") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "Ops Monitor") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "DG_IT_Logistics") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "DG_StrongView") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "OPS Support") { continue; }
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "SYS Support") { continue; }*/


        echo "<div class=\"box\">";
        $userData = $data[$i];

        if(array_key_exists('thumbnailphoto', $userData))
        {
            $fileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'vex');

            $imageParam = basename($fileName);
            $keyParam = md5($secret . $imageParam);

            $fp = fopen($fileName, "wb") or die("Can't open $fileName for writing");

            fwrite($fp, $userData['thumbnailphoto'][0]);
            fclose($fp);

            echo "<div class=\"picture\"><img src=\"pic.php?image=" . rawurlencode($imageParam) . "&key=" . rawurlencode($keyParam) . "\" width=\"96\"></div>";
        }

        echo "Full name: ". $data[$i]["cn"][0] ."<br />";

        if(isset($data[$i]["title"][0])) {
                echo "Title: ". $data[$i]["title"][0] ."<br />";
            } else {
                echo "Title: No title found<br />";
            }
        if(isset($data[$i]["mail"][0])) {
                echo "Email: <a href='mailto:". $data[$i]["mail"][0] ."'> ". $data[$i]["mail"][0] ."</a><br />";
            } else {
                echo "Email: No mail found<br />";
            }
        if(isset($data[$i]["telephonenumber"][0])) {
                echo "Phone: ". $data[$i]["telephonenumber"][0] ."<br /><br />";
            } else {
                echo "Phone: No number found<br /><br />";
            }
    echo "</div>";

    }

/*------------------*/
/* Close Connection */
/*------------------*/

ldap_unbind($ldapconn);

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

edit:

error

Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\wamp\www\vex\ad.php on line 72

What I want to do is: I've got an array, but in that array are values that I don't want in there (I can't do a more specific query (query with LDAP in an OU, but there are computers in there like 'Administrator' or 'Printer', wich I don't want in my overview because I only need "real" employees))

So there is my blacklist

It works if do if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === "blabla") { continue; }, but then i have to do that like 52 times, and a lot of continues...

edit:

```
    $skip = 0;

    foreach ($blacklist as $key => $value){
        if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === $value) { $skip = 1; } 

    }
    if($skip)
        continue;
```

This skips all the values that are in the blacklist array without 100000 notice warnings!

Comment: $i is not defined there. So please define it first

Comment: You need to provide more code..

Comment: Post the error and exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array only has the keys 0-7. If the value of `$i` is anything but one of those values, it is an undefined offset. `print_r($blacklist);` shows the keys and their values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BES Admin
    [1] => Network Administrator
    [2] => SBSMonAcct
    [3] => Directory Updater
    [4] => NL Admin
    [5] => Standard User
    [6] => Standard User with administration links
    [7] => SSL Admin
)
```

Be sure that your variable `$count` is defined and has a value of nothing greater than 8, but I'm guessing that you want exactly 8:

```
$count = count($blacklist);
```

Or you can define your loop as:

```
$blacklist = array("BES Admin","Network Administrator","SBSMonAcct","Directory Updater","NL Admin","Standard User","Standard User with administration links","SSL Admin");
for($i=0; $i<count($blacklist); $i++){
    if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === $blacklist[$i]) { continue; } 
}
```

However, when working with arrays, I prefer to use `foreach` because it keeps track of the number of array items for you:

```
$blacklist = array("BES Admin","Network Administrator","SBSMonAcct","Directory Updater","NL Admin","Standard User","Standard User with administration links","SSL Admin");
foreach ($blacklist as $key => $value){
    if($data[$i]["cn"][0] === $value) { continue; } 
}
```

Comment: Allright, so if there's no match, what would be the best way to avoid this error?

Comment: @user2681510 - The best way is to have exactly the value you need by using `count($blacklist)`.

Comment: @user2681510 - be sure to define your array outside of the loop.

Comment: Allright, I did that, but my code outputs machines that I don't want. The errors are gone tho!

Comment: @user2681510 - That sounds like the topic for a completely different question. This question is about your error, and you posted nothing about your `$data` array nor how you are doing the output.

Comment: I'm sorry about that!

Comment: @user2681510 - You started with a specific question, and now you want someone to debug your entire application. That violates the rules on how questions should be asked, and it's a good way to get downvoted. You need to put a little effort into your own code and learn some basic debugging techniques.

Comment: Fair enough! first time posting here, should of read the rules better! My code was working tho, just getting notices, but when I updated the code to get rid of the errors it didn't work anymore. That's why... I'm gonne remove the values from my array, that should fix it. Thanks alot for helping me guys!